# Casting error when setting source with axSpreadsheet control

Tags: c#, excel, casting, oledb

I use the axSpreadsheet control in C#, but when I set the source there's an error.

> error: can not cast "System.Data.DataTable" to "msdatasrc.DataSource"

My Code:

```
  string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" + "data source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR=YES; IMEX=1'";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        conn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter odda = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [电子订单$]", conn);
        odda.Fill(ds, "table");
        axSpreadsheet1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Then I modify the code: `axSpreadsheet1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` to `axSpreadsheet1.DataSource = (msdatasrc.DataSource)ds.Tables[0];`, and still have the error.

What can I do?

Comment: *there's a error* is not very precise problem description, at least not one that allows us to help.

Comment: hcemp - please read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx and then revise your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious solution is to examine what is `msdatasrc.DataSource`. Create a new instance of it and than copy over the table rows to it, row by row or by using some other tool.